# customizing tab tooltip in gvim to show buffer list

Tags: vim, macvim

Currently running:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep  1 2012 18:08:47)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-646
Compiled by Bjorn Winckler <bjorn.winckler@gmail.com>
```

I have the following code in my .gvimrc which should display a list of all buffers as a tooltip. However, it only shows the list of buffers that are visibly open in the current tab (split windows). The `:buffers` command lists all the buffers properly.

Am I misunderstanding what this code is meant to do (I'm a newbie to Vim scripting; this code was borrowed from an open sourced configuration)?

```
"show tooltips on tabs
  set guitabtooltip=%{GuiTabToolTip()}

" set up tab tooltips with every buffer name
function! GuiTabToolTip()
  let tip = ''
  let bufnrlist = tabpagebuflist(v:lnum)

  for bufnr in bufnrlist
    " separate buffer entries
    if tip!=''
      let tip .= ' | '
    endif

    " Add name of buffer
    let name=bufname(bufnr)
    if name == ''
      " give a name to no name documents
      if getbufvar(bufnr,'&buftype')=='quickfix'
        let name = '[Quickfix List]'
      else
        let name = '[No Name]'
      endif
    endif
    let tip.=name

    " add modified/modifiable flags
    if getbufvar(bufnr, "&modified")
      let tip .= ' [+]'
    endif
    if getbufvar(bufnr, "&modifiable")==0
      let tip .= ' [-]'
    endif
  endfor

  return tip
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the buffer is `tabpagebuflist()`, which, as `:help tabpagebuflist()` explains, is a list of buffer numbers associated with each window in the current tab page.

To get the list of all buffers, you'd have to use something like

```
filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')
```

Comment: Thank you; that worked perfectly! I should have noticed the problem.